# Error: Illegal XML character

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a column with a text data type , but its an xml field.When i try to execute a simple statement like

```
SELECT columnname,
       CONVERT(xml,coloumnname) 
  FROM employee
```

This is running fine in QA since it has small amount to data. When i am running in the prod then the exception shoots up. Is there a way so that it can bypasses all the records which has an illegal xml character so that i can execute the code successfully. Using sql sever 2005/2008.

do anyone have a scrip for this?

Comment: Why exactly are you wanting to convert it to XML? Last time I had to take XML out of a DB I just took it as it was and parsed through it in a datatable and went row through row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate data on-the-fly is slow enough.

1. If you really do not want to use bad data, you should add column to table (e.g. "Is_Validated").
2. Then run script which will check data and if it is converted to xml without exception, update column as 1 else 0.
3. When you run your statement, you should limit converting to xml where Is_Validated=1 only.
4. When you insert new row, check if is valid XML (using TRY/CATCH logic or CLR) and insert only valid rows.
5. When you logic be stable you can begin to validate your bad data.

**Update:**

Because of script from  #2 should be run only one time, it can be simple TSQL:
Assuming you have primary key Id as int and xml column Columnname in Table Employee validated by MySchema

```
 Declare @id int=0,@xml XML(MySchema)
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Id>@Id)
BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 @Id=Id FROM Employee WHERE Id>@Id ORDER BY Id
BEGIN TRY
  SET @xml=(SELECT columnname FROM Employee WHERE id=@Id)
      UPDATE Employee SET Is_Validated=1 WHERE Id=@Id
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE Employee SET Is_Validated=0 WHERE Id=@Id
    END CATCH
    END
```

Comment: thanks dalex for your help, Have you used a script before for this purpose. If so can you please share it?

Answer (score 4):

In all seriousness, you should clean your data.  The set of legal XML characters is specified exactly here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets.

To have any illegal character in XML is bad news.  Instead to trying to "skip over" this data you need to address your root problem which is bad data.

Can you write a script to clean the data in the database?

I suppose it is possible for your live application to read the data and preprocess it, looking for bad characters before you call CONVERT, but this doesn't address the root problem and is not efficient.

Comment: The problem is some times it is not time efficient to "clean up the data", especially if the data is gigantic and you are just using the XML once to load the data into a database.

Comment: Yes, by cleanup I do mean a _one-time_ script, run offline.  Is this not possible?

Comment: I am not sure about his situation, but last time this type of  error cropped up for me I was parsing xml that was over 600 pages long, and I couldn't clean it up because that would require reinserting it into the database, and with Oracle's maximum character limit it was easier to just run a .Replace() while I was parsing.

Comment: I am afraid this will not be possible, So i was trying to skip those particular records with an illegal character. If there exists something like nocheck constrains.

Comment: I take it that the issue is that CONVERT is failing. I don't have access to SQLServer.  Is there an equivalent of ISNULL?  It would be nice if there was something like `SELECT colname, NULLIFFAILS(CONVERT(xml, colname)) FROM ...`.  You could write your own version of CONVERT as a last, last resort.

Comment: Whatever is adding this text into the table is not guaranteeing that only certain characters are being inserted.  That is the problem.  Unless you have manual changes happening.

Comment: +1; "you need to address your root problem which is bad data" - e.g., clean it up this one time, but ultimately you should assert the validity of your data before it is even allowed to be inserted into the DB.  Failing to do that is the root problem, and should be addressed, rather than hacked around.